# pd.low_memory=False no longer works?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am getting the standard warning:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,8,93,584) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

I can't specify types because the data is coming from a csv that comes from sql. There are some NaN interspersed in a column with strings, for example...

typically, I have

```
pd.low_memory=False
```

in pretty much every file that imports pandas... but for some reason that's not working sometimes.

I just upgraded to pandas 23 so that may be part of it?

Also, I'm still using python 2.7...

Comment: have to tired using the `low_memory` param of `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: That works. but before I could just do it once... is that a feature change?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a feature change; however you can change the default for param `low_memory` from `True` to `False` for `pd.read_csv`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join([str(x) for x in range(1000000)] + ['some string'])))
```

will return the error `DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`

you can correct this by using `functools`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import functools
pd.read_csv = functools.partial(pd.read_csv, low_memory=False)
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join([str(x) for x in range(1000000)] + ['some string'])))
```